# Save each result of a loop as an entry in a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, regression

I have a rly complex function so i dont post it here but within this function i want to run a loop . The result of each run should be saved in a vector entry. Also i want to have and if else statement within this loop. 
When i run the loop i get the vector vr but i have only Null entries exept the last entry. How can i adjust  the loop so that every result of the loop is saved in the vector and not only the last one?

```
 for (i in length(y)) {
    if( y[i] == 0) {
      vr[i] <- fittedValuesFullModell[i] - y[i]
    } else {
      vr[i] <- sign(y[i] - fittedValuesFullModell[i]) *
        sqrt(2 *(y[i] * log(y[i] / fittedValuesFullModell[i]) -  
                   (y[i] - fittedValuesFullModell[i]))) 
    }
```

Comment: change for (i in length(y)) { to for (i in 1:length(y)) {

Answer (score 0):

Consider `vapply` or `sapply` designed to iterate through a series and save outputs directly into data structures (i.e., vector, matrix, array) instead of initializing empty ones and filling in loop:

```
vr <- vapply(seq_along(y), function(i) {    
    if( y[i] == 0) {
      fittedValuesFullModell[i] - y[i]
    } else {
      sign(y[i] - fittedValuesFullModell[i]) *
      sqrt(2 *(y[i] * log(y[i] / fittedValuesFullModell[i]) -  
                                (y[i] - fittedValuesFullModell[i]))) 
    }    
}, numeric(length(y)))
```

In fact, looking closer, you may be able to run `mapply` since you are iterating elementwise through *y* and *fittedValuesFullModell* objects with `ifelse()` if single values are being passed into method.

```
vr <- mapply(function(i, j) 
               ifelse(i == 0, f - i, sign(i - f) * sqrt(2 *(i * log(i / f) - (i - f)))),
             y, fittedValuesFullModell)
```